# using PowerShell to rename all files in a folder to each files last write time

Tags: powershell, file-rename

```
$getdate = Get-Date -Format "yyyymmddHHmmss"
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\blah\*.tiff | foreach { rename-item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "($getdate).tif" }
```

This just tells me that the file already exists as if its trying to change them all to the same date and time.

This is what each file should be renamed as though but ending in `.tif` and not `.tiff`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\blah\*  | Get-Date -Format "yyyymmddHHmmss"

20221413111408
20222013112039
20225413115422
20221816071813
```

How do I get this to work so that each file that comes into his folder is renamed when I run this.

I have also tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Blah\*.tiff | foreach { rename-item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "Get-Date -Format ("yyyymmddHHmmss").tif" }
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Rename-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'yyyymmddHHmmss).tif'.
At line:1 char:52
+ ... | foreach { rename-item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "Get-Date -Format  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: Even if the code was right, it's highly likely more than one file can be renamed per second, with your current date time format there will be file collision

Comment: If the files names will be __just a timestamp__, you need to consider a date time format that will make it harder to fail, i.e.: `[datetime]::Now.ToString('yyyymmddHHmmssffff')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently trying to rename all files to the same date timestamp because *you're asking it to* - the value stored in `$getdate` is not going to automatically update itself :)

Instead, you'll want to call `Get-Date` every time you rename an individual file by passing a scriptblock to the `-NewName` parameter - PowerShell will then re-evaluate the scriptblock for every file it's renaming:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\blah*.tiff |Rename-Item -NewName { "$($_ |Get-Date -Format 'yyyymmddHHmmss').tif" }
```

As [Santiago points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534198/using-powershell-to-rename-all-files-in-a-folder-to-each-files-last-write-time/72534294#comment128131042_72534198), this will still fail with a naming collision if you have multiple image files that were last written/modified within the same wallclock second.